# Indices in Numpy and MATLAB

Tags: numpy, matlab, array-indexing

I have a piece of code in Matlab that I want to convert into Python/numpy.

I have a matrix `ind` which has the dimensions (32768, 24). I have another matrix `X` which has the dimensions (98304, 6). When I perform the operation

```
result = X(ind)
```

the shape of the matrix is (32768, 24).

but in numpy when I perform the same shape

```
result = X[ind]
```

I get the shape of the `result` matrix as (32768, 24, 6).

I would greatly appreciate it if someone can help me with why I can these two different results and how can I fix them. I would want to get the shape (32768, 24) for the `result` matrix in numpy as well

Comment: In the numpy case `ind` applies only to the first dimension, e.g. `X[ind,:]`

Comment: @hpaulj this doesn't have any effect in this case. Even if I do what you have suggested, I still get the same results.

Comment: I didn't suggest anything!

Comment: What exactly is the MATLAB doing?  What are the values of `ind` (relative to the shape of `X`)?  My MATLAB coding well in the past, so I can't quite picture the action.  I could fire up `Octave` and do some experimenting, but I prefer that you explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Octave, if I define:

```
>> X=diag([1,2,3,4])
X =

Diagonal Matrix

   1   0   0   0
   0   2   0   0
   0   0   3   0
   0   0   0   4

>> idx = [6 7;10 11]      
idx =

    6    7
   10   11
```

then the indexing selects a block:

```
>> X(idx)
ans =

   2   0
   0   3
```

The `numpy` equivalent is

```
In [312]: X=np.diag([1,2,3,4])
In [313]: X
Out[313]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4]])
In [314]: idx = np.array([[5,6],[9,10]])   # shifted for 0 base indexing
In [315]: np.unravel_index(idx,(4,4))      # raveled to unraveled conversion
Out[315]: 
(array([[1, 1],
        [2, 2]]),
 array([[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]))
In [316]: X[_]         # this indexes with a tuple of arrays
Out[316]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 3]])
```

another way:

```
In [318]: X.flat[idx]
Out[318]: 
array([[2, 0],
       [0, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your help